# JQuery append skips content after spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

I am trying to dynamically append cards inside a `div`.

My code to do that is as follows:

```
    $.getJSON(url, function(jsonresult2) {


        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            phototemp = link_to_photo;
            itemname = link_to_item_name;
            itemcategory = link_to_item_category;


            $("#populateexplore")
                .append('
                       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="float:left">
                       <div class="card"><img src="' 
                       + phototemp 
                       + '" style="width:100%;height:200px;"><div class="container"> <h4> <b> ' 
                       + itemname 
                       + '</b></h4><hr><p>Category:'
                       + itemcategory 
                       + '</p></div></div></div>');
        }
    }).error(function() { sweetAlert("Cannot find the place"); });
```

The **css** of the card `div` is

```
.card {
     box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
     border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corners */
     background-color: #CCC;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that the output cads does not float on the left side and instead gives empty spaces on left

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Asg.jpg

Is there any way I can fill in the void spaces on the left side?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap grid system then why you added ( float:left )  Grid system already have it.

Comment: @yahya 
removing it does not effect the output. it still goes to the right.
i was just giving it a try :)

Comment: I can't be sure cause I don't have the full code or if you can give the website link that may help ..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the third card has a greater height than the rest, and it is blocking the fifth card from floating to the left. Try resizing the cards to all have the same height and seeing if this corrects the issue.

Comment: making every card to same height does fixes it but the content inside every card is different. so some of the text clips out of the card if its long